# Transparent object create opaque alpha channel. How do you get transparent objects over a transparent background?

Tags: rendering, transparency

I have a transparent object that I am rendering without any sort of background, ie film is set to "transparent."
Rather than have slightly transparent pixels, the alpha channel is black and white, no greys.
Is there a way to render a transparent object over a transparent background in such a way that the alpha channel is reflective of the transparency of the object, not just the shape of it?

Comment: Does your transparent object have varying degrees of transparency?

Comment: No, but unless I'm wrong about how it works, I'm expecting that it would appear less transparent towards the edges and almost 100% transparent towards the center, much like the fresnel effect.

Comment: Are you in Cycles? I am guessing so.

Comment: Oops... Sorry: My understanding is that the alpha channel's output carries 1 to 0 info on the sum characteristics of the transparent material.... So the % black or white reflects both transparency and surface color of the transparent material. (If you add a noise node to a transparent material's color input, for example, the alpha output reflects the noise -- but in B&W. ) You can use Set Alpha node to adjust these, but I do not believe any edge-like influence is intended... but I can't find 2.78 docs online right now. All have migrated to 2.8, which is cool but not helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Not presented as an answer so much as extension of comments above: You can add a fresnel and holdout to your material to generate other alpha-node output characteristics... 
[image]